# Visualize SVM predicted data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to predict lung cancer through risk factor wise. I confused whether I am getting correct value or not and What is the best way of visualizing SVM predicted data.

**Script**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('lung_cancer.csv')
dataset.loc[dataset['GENDER'] == 'F', 'GENDER'] = 0
dataset.loc[dataset['GENDER'] == 'M', 'GENDER'] = 1
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0:14].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 15].values

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
C = 1.0 
classifier = SVC(kernel='poly', C=C, decision_function_shape='ovr').fit(X, y)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix  
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)  
class_report = classification_report(y_test,y_pred)
```

**Input file**

```
GENDER  AGE SMOKING YELLOW_FINGERS  ANXIETY PEER_PRESSURE   CHRONIC DISEASE FATIGUE     ALLERGY     WHEEZING    ALCOHOL CONSUMING   COUGHING    SHORTNESS OF BREATH SWALLOWING DIFFICULTY   CHEST PAIN  LUNG_CANCER
F   59  0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
F   63  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
F   75  0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
M   69  0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
M   74  1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
M   63  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
```

Please suggest for the same. Thank you in advance

Comment: 1) pls avoid "what's the best way" etc, especially in titles (edited & removed) 2) pls remove unnecessary parts of your code, such as commented lines (done by myself now) 3) what is *exactly* that you want to visualize? `y_pred`?

Comment: Yes, want to visualize prediction result with the training set and test set. please suggest